# Access to exec to a specific pod in a specific namespace

Tags: kubernetes

I want to grant a user access to exec into one pod not all project pods/components.

i.e. 1 pod <-> 1 namespace <-> 1 user only

Do we have an option like this ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can create the RBAC role and rolebinding for a specific resource by its name.

```yaml
kind: Role
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  namespace: demo
  name: pod-exec-role
rules:
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["pods/exec"]
  resourceNames: ["POD_NAME"]
  verbs: ["get", "create"]
```

And bind that role to a specific user by using the rolebinding:

```yaml
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: pod-exec
  namespace: demo
subjects:
- kind: User
  name: jane 
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
roleRef:
  kind: Role 
  name: pod-exec-role
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

N.B.: This won't work with pods whose names can be changed over time. Like pods created from the `Deployment` object.